# Detect if action is in overflow or action bar

Tags: android, unit-testing, ui-automation, android-uiautomator

I am writing uiautomator tests and I am having a hard time trying to figure out how to click my action bar icons.

If my action is show 'always' its easy to find and click.

If my action is show 'never', I have to click the menu, then click from the menu.  Kind sucks to click menu first.

But what if my action is show 'ifRoom'?  Do I really need to look in action bar first to see if exists and if not click the menu and check there?

Wondering if I am missing an easier way to 'click' action bar stuff in uiautomator regardless of where the action ends up.

Answer (score -1):

When you will use showAsAction="ifRoom". it will put menu in ActionBar if there is space for it unless it will put in overflow menu. It can be accessed from actionbar directly.

Comment: I know how ifRoom works.  That was not my question.  Question is, is there a way to click an action from uiautomator regardless of whether or not it was shown.  Or do I always need to check if it was able to show in action bar first?

Comment: it depends on your other menu Items you have put before this one.

Comment: again, I know that.  I am not asking when/how the menu shows up.  I am  asking if uiautomater has a short cut to get a menu item regardless of where it was placed.